# SQL Server - compare date only between two timedate fields

Tags: sql-server

`Table1` with two columns - `DateTime1` is type `datetimeoffset(7)` and `DateTime2` is type `datetime2(7)`.

Given these two values in the two columns of the same record:

```
DateTime1                               DateTime2
2019-12-17 06:50:12.0000000 +00:00      2019-12-17 06:57:44.3620964
```

If I ran a query based around:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE DateTime1 <> DateTime2
```

I would **NOT** want the above record returned.  I would want these two values evaluated as equal based only on the YYYY-MM-DD values.

I tried with `LEFT` but it doesn't seem to be working correctly, so I think I may need something like `CAST` or `CONVERT`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use CONVERT to only consider the DATE (not time)

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1
WHERE CONVERT(DATE, DateTime1) <> CONVERT(DATE, DateTime2)
```

You could also use DATEDIFF to determine if it is less than 24 hours.